# rabbitmq python - notifications design pattern to scale for thousands of users

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, tornado

Our website has around 50,000 users and daily active traffic is pretty good. We are designing a new notifications feature for our user base.

Our requirement is as follows:

1. Users are part of different Groups.
2. A user can be part of multiple Groups.
3. When a user uploads a image in a group, all the members of that particular group should get a notification saying "new image uploaded" regardless of being online or offline.

We thought of creating rabbitmq exchanges for each group and queue for each user. But got confused going forward of designing the right way!!

Say, a user should receive notifications even he logs-in to site days after the notifications is generated. We ended up storing the messages in DB which is not a good thing at all for offline users.

Can someone suggest proper design pattern with explanation for this use case? We are using celery + rabbitmq + tornado. Should tornado talk directly to the celery consumer? Where do the messages get stored when the user is offline?

Comment: I'd use a XMPP server for this (like ejabberd); notifications via channels is a perfect fit for such a use case (one channel per group).

Comment: Hi Martijn, do you mean using rabbitmq for real-time notifications is a not a good fit for thousands of users. I keep reading use cases like pub-sub pattern being used via rabbitmq. Can you explain in more detail? Thanx

Comment: I'll be implementing similar functionality soon, and XMPP is a better match for the use cases, where the subscribers (end users) are not going to read the messages within a small time frame, and thus you need to store the messages for potentially a long time. There are also vastly differing reliability expectations; if someone misses one new image upload that's not so bad, really.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar project. So how it works:

- Put messages to your rabbit queue, from your events source ( django, celery, everywhere)
- You can use pika+tornado IOLoop ( so when messages come to tornado you will receive notification via pika loop, when request comes http, or websocket connection via Tornado)
- Use collection of opened in TornaodApplication websockets for messaging for users

You can check very close project with logging via torando+rabbitmq on my github: https://github.com/rmuslimov/RapidLog